# tomcat with does start with SSL arguments for JMX

Tags: java, tomcat

I have Tomcat 8.0.23 (I know, should be upgraded) running on CentOS and I need to set up JMX with authentication and SSL. I am able to connect with SSL and with password through SSL tunnel from my windows machine. But when I enter SSL related JVM arguments, the tomcat does not start. I have looked to many documents and I do not see an error in my setup.

```
export JMS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$RMI_PORT -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$RMI_PORT -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -D java.rmi.server.hostname=localhost"
export JMS_NO_AUTH="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
export CONFIG_PATH="/opt/tomcat/default/conf"
export JMS_AUTH="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=$CONFIG_PATH/jmxremote.access -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=$CONFIG_PATH/jmxremote.password"
export JMS_SSL_OFF="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
export JMS_SSL_ON="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=true -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=$CONFIG_PATH/jmx_ssl.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=StupidPassword"

export CATALINA_OPTS="$JMS $JMS_AUTH $JMS_SSL_ON"
```

tomcat logs:

```
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1616; nested exception is:
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

When I switch to no SSL the Tomcat normally starts and I can connect

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="$JMS $JMS_AUTH $JMS_SSL_OFF"
```

Any idea where is the issue?

Comment: I wonder that it may be JVM bug: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13) https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8223331

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the port you define here:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$RMI_PORT
```

is in use. So redefine this variable `RMI_PORT` to point to other port. Or check and stop (if you do not need it) the service which listen on port 1616

Comment: It happens only when these arguments are present: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=true -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=$CONFIG_PATH/jmx_ssl.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=StupidPassword

Comment: When I remove them the tomcat starts successfully on that port.

Comment: sudo netstat -v - a -n -p  | grep 1616 shows only apps like ::ffff:10.29.134.23:61616

Comment: @LeosLiterak, you enter the above config two times. remove one of them and check again

Comment: @LeosLiterak, and use `netstat -an|grep 1616` (on the end you may see the PID)

Comment: There is no app listening on port 1616. There are apps listeing on different port 61616. Which config?

Comment: My mistake, its recommended to have jmxremote and jmxremote.rmi ports to be the same. But check here for localhost: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21552812/2908599